# Can participial phrases describe the actions of a subject other than the first one mentioned?

Tags: grammar, sentence, participial-phrases

I'm still very confused about the correct placement of participial phrases when they describe the action of a noun that isn't the main subject.

*"I eventually saw the film that had everyone talking, creating shock and surprise among the community."*

Does the participial phrase modify the object (meaning *the film* created shock and surprise) or the whole of the preceding clause (as in, the act of the narrator seeing the film created shock and surprise)? If it's the latter, then that means I shouldn't use constructions like this, because that is not the intended meaning.

Comment: This has been answered (in general) before. Participle clauses (they're not analysed as phrases by many nowadays) can attach to various precursors, and may indeed give rise to ambiguities. This example _is_ ambiguous, though I doubt the ' "my" seeing the film giving rise to shock ...' reading is very likely. With less obvious (or perverse, where the less likely reading is intended) examples, rephrasing is certainly necessary. "I eventually saw the film that had everyone talking, the film creating shock and surprise among the community." vs ...

Comment: "Generating shock and surprise among the community, I eventually saw the film that had had everyone talking."

Comment: If anybody gives you a rule for this, it will be a rule that somebody has made up and put in a grammar book, not a rule of the real grammar that governs how English speakers use English. As Edwin says, constructions like this are formally ambiguous, and only real-world information lets you choose the interpretation that fits.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I guess I'm the type of person who likes there to be hard-and-fast rules that I can always follow, but that does not seem to be the case with participial phrases

Answer (score 1):

> "I eventually saw the film that had everyone talking, creating shock and surprise among the community."

The sentence is so poor that I would mark it wrong.

At first view it appears that *creating shock and surprise among the community* is the result of *everyone talking*,

A better view might be that *creating shock and surprise among the community* is the result of your eventually seeing the film.

*that had everyone talking* is a relative clause and creates a noun phrase out of “the film that had everyone talking”. As it is a noun phrase, it can be replaced by *”it”* . Thus

"I eventually saw **it**, creating shock and surprise among the community."

Additionally, the function of the participle “creating” is unclear; the function of the comma in the sentence is not at all clear - it does not appear to be conjunctive.

As a side note, the use of participles and participle phrases and clauses is not as common as students seem to think. Native speakers use them sparingly as they often lead to ambiguity (as we see from your example). Students think this way as a lot of time is spent in teaching them, but this time is not proportional to their use.

My advice is not to use them until you fully understand them and their application.

Comment: Would you say the constructions themselves are confusing or are the examples only ambiguous because of the lack of context? I'm trying to understand if it's ever acceptable to use a participial clause that modifies a noun that's part of a larger noun phrase, but I'm still not sure. For instance: "The river ran through the wood and under the bridge that James had whiled away entire afternoons on, thinking about nothing in particular." Most sources would say that a participial clause placed here would be modifying the main subject, the river, but I think it's unambiguously referring to James.

Comment: *that James had whiled away entire afternoons on, (conjunctive comma) thinking about nothing in particular* is awkward, to say the least: *upon which James, thinking about nothing in particular, had whiled away entire afternoons*, is better.

Comment: OK, thank you. What do you mean by a conjunctive comma? I have never heard that terminology used before and can't find anything about it online.

Comment: Conjunctive commas are commas that can be replaced by a conjunction.

Comment: OK, so in my example it could be replaced by the subordinate conjunction "while," giving us "the bridge that James had whiled away entire afternoons on while thinking about nothing in particular." (I know that's not a very good sentence, but I'm just trying to understand the function of conjunctive commas.)

Comment: That's the general idea. But while you can substitute almost any conjunction with a comma, the choice of conjunction to use in place of a comma is not always so easy.